# Deserializing an Object Name with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON that I need to deserialize into a C# object.  It has a bit of an odd design.

```
{
    "2052626192": {
        "p": 0,
        "u": 0,
        "w": ["2052626181", "2052626203"],
        "o": 0,
        "b": 0,
        "df": 0.648749,
        "l": -1,
        "y": -0.178449,
        "s": 0,
        "t": "",
        "n": "DG Suhail 2.151A",
        "a": 0,
        "x": 0.646587
    },
    "2052387279": {
        "b": 1,
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

The entire list of objects represents a universe, and each object is a galaxy in that universe.  Every galaxy has the unique ID that defines the object (etc. "2052387279").

Because the properties of this API are not very descriptive, I've used JSON.net's custom property indicator.  I have a class called `Galaxy` that looks like this.  (Note that it does not contain all properties in the JSON yet).

```
namespace SonataKit
{
    public class Galaxy
    {
        // set up some properties
        // API: top level object
        public string ID { get; set; }

        // array of galaxy IDs that are connected
        // API: 'w'
        [JsonProperty("w")]
        public List<string> Connections { get; set; }

        // galaxy name
        // API: 'n'
        [JsonProperty("n")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // danger factor
        // API: 'df'
        [JsonProperty("df")]
        public string DangerFactor { get; set; }
        }
}
```

And I have a container class called `Universe`

```
namespace SonataKit
{
    public class Universe
    {
        public List<Galaxy> Galaxies { get; set; }

        public static void GetListFromJSON(string json)
        {
            var universe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Universe>(json);

            foreach (Galaxy galaxy in galaxies.Galaxies)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(galaxy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running into a few problems.

How can I get the object ID name with JSON.net?  Because it is listed as the object name and not as a key-value property, I am unsure how to parse it even after looking through documentation.

To clarify - I need to get the value `2052626192` from the first object, and put it into a property in my `Galaxy` class named `ID`.

Using the website json2csharp.com, I get the following when I input only the first object.

```
public class __invalid_type__2052626192
{
    public int p { get; set; }
    public int u { get; set; }
    public List<string> w { get; set; }
    public int o { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public double df { get; set; }
    public int l { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public int s { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string n { get; set; }
    public int a { get; set; }
    public double x { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public __invalid_type__2052626192 __invalid_name__2052626192 { get; set;    }
}
```

obviously, this would not work as `__invalid_type__2052626192` would not work for all the objects in the array.

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably deserialize into a `Dictionary<long,Galaxy>` then update each value with its key yourself.

Comment: @Blorgbeard that worked perfectly!  Thanks.